# Ubuntu script language doesn't work as expect

Tags: bash, shell

As a beginner of `bash` script, I wrote a simple script to change the directory. Here it is my source code:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
echo "---------------------START-----------"
cd /home/cocadas/Workspace/carnd/CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3
```

I save it as "start" in the `/root` folder. I change the property of the file to be executable, and then run it as below. The problem is that the execution command `cd` doesn't work. What did I miss?

```
cocadas@cocadas-ThinkPad-W540:~$ ./start
+ echo ---------------------START-----------
---------------------START-----------
+ cd /home/cocadas/Workspace/carnd/CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3 cocadas@cocadas-ThinkPad-W540:~$ cd
/home/cocadas/Workspace/carnd/CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3
cocadas@cocadas-ThinkPad-W540:~/Workspace/carnd/CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `./start` call creates a sub shell. Run `source start` or `. start` (`.` is an abbreviation of `source`) instead to execute your script directly in your command line, not in a nested container.